# Why does a Secondary Cell have a lower internal resistance than a Primary one?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, batteries

Hi I was wondering why would a secondary cell have a lower internal resistance than a primary cell. I had read somewhere it was due to the fact secondary cells used lead acid which has a lower resistance but I was hoping to get more information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secondary cells, like lead acid, are made of wet cells giving them low resistance whereas primary cells, like alkaline batteries, don't normally have fluid inside the cells, which is why they are often referred to as "dry cells", making their internal resistance higher. Because of their lower internal resistance secondary cells have higher discharge currents than primary cells. Secondary cells generally have lower energy density, but they can be recharged whereas primary cells cannot.

Hope this helps.